# F# equivalent of C# code outputting differently, possible math difference?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have come to liking C# and DOTNET programming after sticking my feet in it.

I have this functioning C# code :

```
/*
Name : paintRoomCalc in C#
Author : Аїӡек Меѥҏ
Version : v1.0
License : N/A
*/


using System;
class MainClass
{
    static public void getLayers(float roomWidth, float roomDepth, float roomHeight, float paintThick)
    {
        float edgeArea, edgeSideDepthArea, edgeSideDepthVol, edgeSideWidthArea, edgeSideWidthVol, edgeUpArea, edgeUpVol, edgeVol, roomVol, wallArea, wallFive, wallOne, wallThree, wallVol;
        double i = 0;
        double t = 0;
        roomWidth = roomWidth * 12;
        roomDepth = roomDepth * 12;
        roomHeight = roomHeight * 12;
        roomVol = roomWidth * roomDepth * roomHeight;
        while (roomVol >= 0)
        {
            // account for walls
            wallOne = (float)(roomWidth * roomHeight);
            wallThree = (float)(roomDepth * roomHeight);
            wallFive = (float)(roomDepth * roomWidth);

            wallVol = (float)(((wallOne * 2) + (wallThree * 2) + wallFive) * paintThick);
            wallArea = (float)((wallOne * 2) + (wallThree * 2) + wallFive);

            roomWidth = (float)(roomWidth - (paintThick * 2));
            roomDepth = (float)(roomDepth - (paintThick * 2));
            roomHeight = (float)(roomHeight - (paintThick * 2));

            // account for edges going up & down
            edgeUpVol = (float)(roomHeight * Math.Pow(paintThick, 2));
            edgeUpVol = (float)(edgeUpVol * 2);
            edgeUpArea = (float)(roomHeight * paintThick);
            edgeUpVol = (float)(edgeUpArea * 2);

            // account for edges going side to side {on ceiling}
            //// account for edges going side to side {depth}
            edgeSideDepthVol = (float)(roomDepth * Math.Pow(paintThick, 2));
            edgeSideDepthVol = (float)(edgeSideDepthVol * 2);
            edgeSideDepthArea = (float)(roomDepth * paintThick);
            //// account for edges going side to side {width}
            edgeSideWidthVol = (float)(roomWidth * Math.Pow(paintThick, 2));
            edgeSideWidthVol = (float)(edgeSideWidthVol * 2);
            edgeSideWidthArea = (float)(roomWidth * paintThick);

            // add edges
            edgeVol = (float)(edgeUpVol + edgeSideWidthVol + edgeSideDepthVol);
            edgeArea = (float)(edgeUpArea + edgeSideWidthArea + edgeSideDepthArea);

            // calculate final values
            roomVol = (float)(roomVol - wallVol - edgeVol);
            wallArea = (float)(wallArea - edgeArea);

            i += 1;
            t += wallArea;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i + " layers to fill your room with paint!!");
        Console.WriteLine("& " + t / 4800 + " gallons of paint");
    }
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float roomWidth, roomDepth, roomHeight, paintThickMil;
        float paintThick;
        Console.WriteLine("Paint Layer Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("by : Аїӡек Меѥҏ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //get input for room dimentions
        Console.Write("Room Width in Feet? ");
        roomWidth = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Room Depth in Feet? ");
        roomDepth = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Room Height in Feet? ");
        roomHeight = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("1 mil is 1/1000 of an inch");
        Console.Write("Paint Thickness in Mils? ");
        paintThickMil = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        paintThick = paintThickMil / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");

        getLayers(roomWidth, roomDepth, roomHeight, paintThick);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

and I tried to translate it to F# as best I could :

```
(*
Name : paintRoomCalc in C#
Author : Аїӡек Меѥҏ
Version : b0.1
License : N/A
*)

open System;

let getLayers (rW:float) (rD:float) (rH:float) (pT:float) : int = 
    let paintThick = pT;
    let mutable i = 0;
    let mutable t = 0.0;
    let mutable roomWidth = (float rW)*12.0;
    let mutable roomDepth = (float rD)*12.0;
    let mutable roomHeight = (float rH)*12.0;
    let mutable edgeArea = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideDepthArea = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideDepthVol = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideWidthArea = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideWidthVol = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeUpArea = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeUpVol = 0.0; 
    let mutable edgeVol = 0.0;
    let mutable roomVol = 0.0;
    let mutable wallArea = 0.0;
    let mutable wallFive = 0.0; 
    let mutable wallOne = 0.0;
    let mutable wallThree = 0.0;
    let mutable wallVol = 0.0;
    let mutable roomVol = roomWidth * roomDepth * roomHeight;
    while (float roomVol) >= 0.0 do
        // account for walls
        wallOne <- (float roomWidth) * (float roomHeight);
        wallThree <- (float roomDepth) * (float roomHeight);
        wallFive <- (float roomDepth) * (float roomWidth);

        wallVol <- (((float wallOne) * 2.0) + ((float wallThree) * 2.0) + (float wallFive)) * (float paintThick);
        wallArea <- (((float wallOne) * 2.0) + ((float wallThree) * 2.0) + (float wallFive));

        roomWidth <- ((float roomWidth) - ((float paintThick) * 2.0));
        roomDepth <- ((float roomDepth) - ((float paintThick) * 2.0));
        roomHeight <- ((float roomHeight) - ((float paintThick) * 2.0));

        // account for edges going up & down
        edgeUpVol <- ((float roomHeight) * Math.Pow((float paintThick), 2.0));
        edgeUpVol <- ((float edgeUpVol) * 2.0);
        edgeUpArea <- ((float roomHeight) * (float paintThick));
        edgeUpVol <- ((float edgeUpArea) * 2.0);

        // account for edges going side to side {on ceiling}
        //// account for edges going side to side {depth}
        edgeSideDepthVol <- ((float roomDepth) * Math.Pow((float paintThick), 2.0));
        edgeSideDepthVol <- ((float edgeSideDepthVol) * 2.0);
        edgeSideDepthArea <- ((float roomDepth) * (float paintThick));
        //// account for edges going side to side {width}
        edgeSideWidthVol <- ((float roomWidth) * Math.Pow((float paintThick), 2.0));
        edgeSideWidthVol <- ((float edgeSideWidthVol) * 2.0);
        edgeSideWidthArea <- ((float roomWidth) * (float paintThick));

        // add edges
        edgeVol <- ((float edgeUpVol) + (float edgeSideWidthVol) + (float edgeSideDepthVol));
        edgeArea <- ((float edgeUpArea) + (float edgeSideWidthArea) + (float edgeSideDepthArea));

        // calculate final values
        roomVol <- ((float roomVol) - (float wallVol) - (float edgeVol));
        wallArea <- ((float wallArea) - (float edgeArea));

        i <- i + 1;
        t <- (float wallArea) + (float t);
    Console.WriteLine((string i) + " layers to fill your room with paint!!");
    Console.WriteLine("& " + (string (t / 4800.0)) + " gallons of paint");
    0;

let input1:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
let input2:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
let input3:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
let input4:float = float(Console.ReadLine());

getLayers input1 input2 input3 input4;
```

Let it be noted that those input variables will be renamed in the future and I will properly do some parity changes once the overall math things are done.

Also, I know this isn't great code, I'm still new to F# & C#.

Here's the difference :
when using 1,2,3 & 1 (in that order), for the input, I get two vastly different answers.

in F# I get :

```
5 layers to fill your room with paint!!
& 2.01875 gallons of paint
```

in C# I get :

```
6668 layers to fill your room with paint!!
& 2078.3967309443156 gallons of paint
```

My guess it has something to do with my typecasting with the absurd amount of float casts

TL;DR : What should I change in the F# program so that the two programs are equivalent, mathmatically, so that they give the same results?

Comment: `What should I change in these two programs so that they are equivalent` it depends, which one is correct?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  the c# is correct

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to divide input4 by 1000.0 to get the mil equivalent.
it was treating it as-is.
simple mistake.

I also removed the ugly c-like `return 0;` in the function `getLayers`, and replaced it with a return list. This is read from the return of `getLayers` in the final output in :
`answer.[0]` & `answer.[1]`

completed code (with parity) :

```
(*
Name : paintRoomCalc in F#
Author : Аїӡек Меѥҏ
Version : v1.0
License : N/A
*)

open System;

let getLayers (rW:float) (rD:float) (rH:float) (pT:float) : float list = 
    let paintThick = pT;
    let mutable i = 0;
    let mutable t = 0.0;
    let mutable roomWidth:float = (float rW)*12.0;
    let mutable roomDepth:float = (float rD)*12.0;
    let mutable roomHeight:float = (float rH)*12.0;
    let mutable edgeArea:float = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideDepthArea:float = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideDepthVol:float = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideWidthArea:float = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeSideWidthVol:float = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeUpArea:float = 0.0;
    let mutable edgeUpVol:float = 0.0; 
    let mutable edgeVol:float = 0.0;
    let mutable roomVol:float = 0.0;
    let mutable wallArea:float = 0.0;
    let mutable wallFive:float = 0.0; 
    let mutable wallOne:float = 0.0;
    let mutable wallThree:float = 0.0;
    let mutable wallVol:float = 0.0;
    let mutable roomVol:float = (float roomWidth) * (float roomDepth) * (float roomHeight);
    while (float roomVol) >= 0.0 do
        // account for walls
        wallOne <- (float roomWidth) * (float roomHeight);
        wallThree <- (float roomDepth) * (float roomHeight);
        wallFive <- (float roomDepth) * (float roomWidth);

        wallVol <- (((float wallOne) * 2.0) + ((float wallThree) * 2.0) + (float wallFive)) * (float paintThick);
        wallArea <- (((float wallOne) * 2.0) + ((float wallThree) * 2.0) + (float wallFive));

        roomWidth <- ((float roomWidth) - ((float paintThick) * 2.0));
        roomDepth <- ((float roomDepth) - ((float paintThick) * 2.0));
        roomHeight <- ((float roomHeight) - ((float paintThick) * 2.0));

        // account for edges going up & down
        edgeUpVol <- ((float roomHeight) * Math.Pow((float paintThick), 2.0));
        edgeUpVol <- ((float edgeUpVol) * 2.0);
        edgeUpArea <- ((float roomHeight) * (float paintThick));
        edgeUpVol <- ((float edgeUpArea) * 2.0);

        // account for edges going side to side {on ceiling}
        //// account for edges going side to side {depth}
        edgeSideDepthVol <- ((float roomDepth) * Math.Pow((float paintThick), 2.0));
        edgeSideDepthVol <- ((float edgeSideDepthVol) * 2.0);
        edgeSideDepthArea <- ((float roomDepth) * (float paintThick));
        //// account for edges going side to side {width}
        edgeSideWidthVol <- ((float roomWidth) * Math.Pow((float paintThick), 2.0));
        edgeSideWidthVol <- ((float edgeSideWidthVol) * 2.0);
        edgeSideWidthArea <- ((float roomWidth) * (float paintThick));

        // add edges
        edgeVol <- ((float edgeUpVol) + (float edgeSideWidthVol) + (float edgeSideDepthVol));
        edgeArea <- ((float edgeUpArea) + (float edgeSideWidthArea) + (float edgeSideDepthArea));

        // calculate final values
        roomVol <- ((float roomVol) - (float wallVol) - (float edgeVol));
        wallArea <- ((float wallArea) - (float edgeArea));

        i <- i + 1;
        t <- (float wallArea) + (float t);
    [float i; t];

    

Console.WriteLine("Paint Layer Calculator");
Console.WriteLine("by : Аїӡек Меѥҏ");
Console.WriteLine();

//get input for room dimentions
Console.Write("Room Width in Feet? ");
let roomWidthI:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Room Depth in Feet? ");
let roomDepthI:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Room Height in Feet? ");
let roomHeightI:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("1 mil is 1/1000 of an inch");
Console.Write("Paint Thickness in Mils? ");
let mutable paintThickI:float = float(Console.ReadLine());
paintThickI <- float(paintThickI / 1000.0);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");

let answer = getLayers roomWidthI roomDepthI roomHeightI paintThickI;
Console.WriteLine((string answer.[0]) + " layers to fill your room with paint!!");
Console.WriteLine("& " + (string (answer.[1] / 4800.0)) + " gallons of paint");
```

Comment: One nice thing about F# is that it gives you the tools to avoid that kind of mistakes. Look into the measurements language feature.